# "Feature Tour" vs "Features Tour"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Documentation for a piece of software will often include a tour of its features. Sometimes this is called "Feature Tour", and sometimes "Features Tour". From querying web search engines, it would seem that "Feature Tour" is twice as frequent, both being widely used. Can someone expand on the correctness of both, the subtle difference in meaning, and/or reasons to prefer either form?

Comment: *Feature Tour* is a tour of features like *apple tree* is a tree of apples.

Comment: @Good A.M. _Features Tour_ is a tour of features like _systems analysts_ are people who 'who identify the organizational improvements needed, design systems to implement those changes, and train and motivate others to use the systems.' [Wikipedia]. And by the way, an apple tree is only a tree of apples before the kids have been at it.

Comment: The apples are for the kids first, @EdwinAshworth, so if you want any apples for yourself, you will need an *apple orchard*! Wouldn't either way be acceptable, and beyond the phonetic aggravation of the extra *s*, what advantage would one expression have over the other? As the duplicate implies, the indefinite article complicates things if you found yourself referring to ***a** Features Tour*.

Comment: I was pointing out that your (at least implied) parallel isn't convincing evidence, though it seems presented to appear as such. With unusual pairings, the singular attributive is usually chosen unless there is considered to be a real need to emphasise  plurality, but there is no authority dictating that this must be the correct option. Often, usage is divided, with one variant becoming more established over time. // What's wrong with _a_ sports centre?